# SQL запрос из 2х таблиц с сортировкой

Tags: sql

Написать SQL запрос, который выведет данные о всех заказах, дата создания которых меньше текущей даты на один месяц. В результирующем списке должны быть выведены: номер заказа и наименование контрагента. Если контрагент в заказе не указан – вывести «Отсутствует».

```
•   Таблица заказов Orders с полями:
ord_id — ID заказа;
ord_num — номер заказа;
ord_datetime — дата и время создания заказа;
ord_сtr — ID контрагента.
•   Таблица контрагентов Сontractors с полями:
сtr_id — ID контрагента;
сtr_name — наименование контрагента;
```

Comment: *данные о всех заказах, дата создания которых меньше текущей даты на один месяц.* Строго 1 месяц? т.е. данные за один день? А если в предыдущем месяце такого числа просто нет (скажем, сегодня 30 марта)? *Если контрагент в заказе не указан – вывести «Отсутствует».* Функция COALESCE().

Comment: JOIN(какой именно зависит от ваших целей) вам в помощь по ID контрагента , SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-1 DAY),INTERVAL -1 MONTH) as «первое число предыдущего месяца» - как пример для даты. Биржа фриланса - для заказа готового решения, если самому лень разбираться.